# I can't load image and text in some platform from res/raw

Tags: java, android, getresource

I have layout that my images and text files in "res/raw" folder are load by user search.
image's name start with ("p"+month+"_"+day) and the text file start with "t".
when user search date java create file name by month and day.
but this is not show image and text on the some platform like tablet 10" & sony xperia T

Image

```
String MD = (jCal.toString().substring(5)); // 2014-03-25 => 03-25
String[] Split_MD = MD.split("-");
String mDrawableName = ("p"+Split_MD[0]+"_"+Split_MD[1]);
ImageView Pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Resources res = getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "raw", getPackageName());
Pic.setImageResource(resId);
```

Text

```
    TextView txtContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    String mAssetsName = ("raw/t"+Split_MD[0]+"_"+Split_MD[1]);
    txtContent.setTypeface(face);

    try {
        Resources res1 = getResources();
        InputStream in_s = res1.openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(mAssetsName,"raw", getPackageName()));

        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
        txtContent.setText(new String(b));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        txtContent.setText("Error: can't show help.");
    }
```

Logcat:

```
D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 7% free 2430K/2592K, paused 72ms, total 77ms
I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.075MB for 614416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 3029K/3196K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3029K/3196K, paused 8ms+5ms, total 90ms
D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 21K, 5% free 3184K/3328K, paused 253ms, total 273ms
I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.810MB for 614416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 4% free 3779K/3932K, paused 12ms+69ms, total 253ms
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: cannot understand your question because you refuse to use punctuation.

Comment: @jb15613 sorry I fix it

Comment: Can you post a logcat or console output?

Comment: Nobody can help me???